# SQL Server 2008, Books Online, and old documentation

Tags: sql-server-2008, documentation

*[I have no idea if stackoverflow really is right right place for this, but don't know how many devs on here run into msi issues with SQL Server; suggest SuperUser or ServerFault if folk think it's better on either of those]*

About a year ago, when we were looking at moving our codebase forward and migrating to SQL Server 2008, I pulled down a copy of Books Online from the MSDN. Reviewed, did background research, fed results upstream, grabbed Express and tinkered with that.

Then we got the nod to move forward (hurrah!) this past couple of weeks. So armed with Developer Edition, and running through the install, I've since found out I've zapped the Books Online MSI, no-ones got a copy of it, and Microsoft only have a later version (Oct 2009) available, so damned if I can update my SQL Server fully and properly... {mutter grumble}.

Does anyone know if old versions of Books Online are available for download anywhere? Poking around the Microsoft download centre can't find it, neither is my google-fu finding it. For reference, I'm looking for SQLServer2008_BOL_August2008_ENU.msi ...

This may just be a case of good ol' manual delete the files and (try) and clean up the registry :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this down, it ended up being a case of trying to wipe it out manually - a tedious exercise. It seemed to be a success, but without having the original MSIs I wasn't ever able to determine how much cruft was left over.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the August 2008 version is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc514207.aspx  but it redirects to the generic BOL page now

Comment: Yep - that's the problem I've got... which means I can't get my local copy of Books Online updated...

Comment: you need to get the latest version from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc514207.aspx

that is the latest version

Comment: the problem is I can't upgrade the old version: any update means removing the old August 2008 version, and I don't have the MSI for it lying about -- all updates fail as the installers fail when then try and remove the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in the binaries for SQL Server on DVD/MSDN images?

I see "SQLServer2008_BOL.msi" in X:\x86\Setup in my ISO image

Perhaps this will do the trick...

Comment: Already tried that. Took a copy and renamed ... and it failed. It's clever to know it's not the right version.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an [installer clean up utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) which will help you remove the old version of books online.  Then you can go forward with an install of the latest version.

Comment: Books Online's installer doesn't appear in the list...